# Sublime Text 2 Package Control Installation trouble. No Package Control option under Preferences

Tags: installation, sublime-text-2

I am trying to install an REPL for Sublime Text 2. I followed the both the simple and the manual installation procedures as per the instructions at https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2

However, There is no Package Control menu option under Preferences. According to the install instructions for the REPL this should be an option. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL

So how to create a Package Control menu option under Preferences and what am I doing wrong with this install?

Comment: Did you restart Sublime after pasting the code into the Sublime console?

Comment: Yes, by xing out and then opening it back up.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Mac OS x Yosemite

Comment: You need to completely quit Sublime by hitting `⌘-Q` or going to **`Sublime Text 2 -> Quit`**. Just closing the window by hitting the red button doesn't do anything - Sublime is still running.